# Validation not working in PHP on submission the form data by click the submit button

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, insertion

Validation not working in php  on submission the form data by click the submit button.

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST['validate'])) {
            if (empty($_POST['ename'])){
                $nameErr = "name is required";
            }
            else{
                $name = test_input($_POST['ename']);
                 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
              $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
                }
            if (empty($_POST['mail'])){
                $emailErr = "email is required";
                }
            else{
                $email = test_input($_POST['mail']);
            }
            if (empty($_POST['gender'])){
                $genderErr = "gender is required";
            }
            else{
                $gender = test_input($_POST['gender']);
            }
```

i want stop empty insertion

```
            $query = "insert into inserttb (name,email,gender) values ('$name','$email','$gender')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            if(!$result){
            echo "data insertion failed";
            }
            }
            //function to validate the input data
            function test_input($data) {
              $data = trim($data);
              $data = stripslashes($data);
              $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
              return $data;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Before your query check if `$nameErr`, `$emailErr` or `$genderErr` are set and only insert if they are not.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?
(added var $someErrorFound)

```
     if (isset($_POST['validate'])) {
            if (empty($_POST['ename'])){
                $nameErr = "name is required";
                $someErrorFound=true;
            }
            else{
                $name = test_input($_POST['ename']);
                 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
              $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                $someErrorFound=true;
            }
                }
            if (empty($_POST['mail'])){
                $emailErr = "email is required";
                $someErrorFound=true;
                }
            else{
                $email = test_input($_POST['mail']);
                $someErrorFound=true;
            }
            if (empty($_POST['gender'])){
                $genderErr = "gender is required";
                $someErrorFound=true;
            }
            else{
                $gender = test_input($_POST['gender']);
                $someErrorFound=true;
            }

   if ($someErrorFound==false)
    {
      //insert into DB
    } else //don't insert
```

Comment: Absolutely. Of course you can tidy the code or extend the functionality so you use one return variable per check e.g. $emaliEmpty, $emailNotValid, you can make array from them $checks['emial']=true, $checks['gender']=true... It depends on what you are in the end doing with these checks...  Basically it's exactly what @kerbholz was suggesting in the first comment.